# Is it possible to create AppIcons using SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I would find it a lot simpler to just design an AppIcon declaratively using SwiftUI as opposed to creating image files. Is this possible? For example:

```
struct AppIcon: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 128, height: 128)
                .foregroundStyle(.indigo)
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .font(.system(size: 82)).bold()
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: No, your icon must be an image assert. However, you could screenshot what you create in SwiftUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Apple Developer guidelines, app icons must be pngs. This *can* be done in `SwiftUI`, by converting your view into an image for export. There is a good article about it here:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-convert-a-swiftui-view-to-an-image
However, it is recommended that you use a dedicated design tool for creating app icons, such as
[Figma.](https://figma.com)